# Searching for the comprehensive guide to creating Crypto Currency

Tags: client

A few months ago I came across (by accident) a very detailed and well written guide on how to create your own crypto-currency from the bitcoin source code.  I skimmed through it and "Stared" in Firefox for future reference.

Now that I want to read through it I can't find it in my bookmarks. (I sometimes think Firefox is not saving them), anyway...

The guide had highlighted source code, complete explanations of what was necessary, how to generate the genesis block, etc.  He even offered a service were he would do it all for you.

Does any one have the link to that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be it? It seems to be what you're asking for.

https://andarazoroflove.org/how-to-create-alt-coin-scrypt-clones-for-fun-and-profit-bitcoin-litecoin-secrets-exposed/

Comment: Yep! that's it.

Comment: This link is now defunct. Does anyone have this guide? Please advise.

Comment: I suspect with this kind of question you're better off asking in the Altcoin section of Bitcointalk than here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=67.0.  But there are already so many altcoins that I'd take a hard look at the existing ones before really creating new ones.  Here's a listing of the existing Altcoins: http://altcoins.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since it's gone, you can find it here :-    http://archive.today/FoyXL